# What is the difference between “comorbidity” and “multimorbidity”?

Tags: terminology

I am doing a search on how the number of conditions can cause disease burden. I came across the terms *comorbidity* and *multimorbidty* in my search and I wanted to know the difference between the two.

Here are some definitions I found, and I was hoping someone might clear them up for me?

> comorbidity – describes medical conditions that exist at the time of diagnosis of the index disease or later, but that are not a consequence of the index disease
>
> multimorbidity – coexistence of several chronic diseases; can be described as existence of two or more chronic diseases.

Answer (score 3):

*Comorbidity* describes the presence of one or more conditions beside another condition of interest. It can also refer to each of these accompanying conditions. For example:

- Comorbidity (or comorbidities) of x usually include(s) y and z.
- In a study of patients with type 2 diabetes (the main in the study), common comorbidities may include obesity, hypertension, coronary artery disease, among others.

*Multimorbidity*, refers merely to coexistence of multiple (>=2) conditions, without specifying a main condition of interest. For example:

- A patient with multi-morbidity has the conditions x, y, and z at the same time.
- A patient with coronary artery disease, obesity and hypertension is a patient with multimorbidity. S/he is likely to be on polypharmacy (taking multiple medications for those coexisting conditions).

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced answers can be deleted by community vote.